# Choosing grandparent table of db with Django

Tags: python, django

I need to open grandparent object with child's id with following model:

```
class Grandparent(models.Model):
    grandparent_name = CharField(max_length=20)

class Parent(models.Model):
    grandparent = ForeignKey(Grandparent)
    parent_name = CharField(max_length=20)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = ForeignKey(Parent)
    child_name = CharField(max_length=20)
```

Staying on Child's list page I want to go directly to it's Grandparent.

I had an idea to use SQL request in my view something like this:

```
def grandparent_detail(request, child_id):
     context = {'grandparent_id':grandparent_id}
         grand= Grandparent.objects.raw(SELECT grandparent_id
         FROM myapp_Grandparent WHERE
         GRandparent.grandparent_id = Parent.parent_id
         AND Parent.parent_id = Child.child_id)
     return render(request, 'myapp/grandparent_detail.html', {'grandparent_id':grandparent_id})
```

But it doesn't work.

Could you give me an advise if there's an instrument in Django to make such structural requests? Thank you.

**My final aim** is to be able to link grandparent/parent/child from childrens list page with such url patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.childrenlist, name = 'childrenlist'),
url(r'^grandparents/<grandparent_id>[0-9]+/$', 
    views.grandparent, name = 'grandparent'),
url(r'^grandparents/<grandparent_id>[0-9]+/parents/
    <parent_id>[0-9]+/$', views.parent, name = 'parent'),
url(r'^grandparents/<grandparent_id>[0-9]+/parents/
    <parent_id>[0-9]+/children/<child_id>[0-9]+/$', 
    views.parent, name = child'),
```

Can you please show example of proper  tag if I only know the Child_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So final solution I found for my case is following link in template:

```
<a href="/myapp/grandparents/{{ child.parent.grandparent_id }}/parents/{{ child.parent_id }}/children/{{ child_id }}/">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Parent.objects.filter(
    grandparent=grandparent_id,
    child__parent_id=parent_id
    ).select_related('grandparent')
```

template:

```
{{ parent.grandparent.grandparent_name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set up a [ForeignKey in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) you can access the foreign object using its property such that this view:

```
def grandparent_detail(request, child_id):
     grandparent = Child.objects.get(id=child_id).parent.grandparent
     return render(request, 'myapp/grandparent_detail.html', {'grandparent':grandparent})
```

Will allow you to access the grandparent object in the template. No SQL needed.

For reference, you can access the `Parent` objects of a grandparent either in code or in templates like so:

```
grandparent.parent_set.all() # A queryset of related parents
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Child.objects.first().parent.grandparent.grandparent_name
```

which probably generates 1 sql command for each Child instance.

(From my Django guru:) You can optimize this and select everything in single SQL command

```
for child in Child.objects.select_related('parent__grandparent'):
    child.parent.grandparent.grandparent_name
```

I have tested this and for at least dj 3.0 this works.

Comment: ... and to make your urls you can use: "child.parent.id", "child.parent.grandparent_id". So in this case we don't need anything from grandparents table, single join is enough, and just ".select_related('parent')" optimizes it.

Comment: one comment more, nothing to this question but to be complete (I have found this answer while solving the mm:m:1 relation together with serializers). In DRF (Rest Framework) you will not write source="child.parent.id" but source="parent.id" only. Or source="parent.grandparent.grandparent_name".